# Vim: matching html attribute names

Tags: regex, vim

The following syntax rules:

```
" #f6266e
syntax match tagOperator "\v\<\/?\w+\s*[^>]*\>" contains=tagFunction,tagFunctionDefinition
hi def link tagOperator Operator

" #a6e22e
syntax match tagFunctionDefinition "\v\<" contained
syntax match tagFunctionDefinition "\v\>" contained
syntax match tagFunctionDefinition "\v/" contained
hi def link tagFunctionDefinition Function
```

produce this:

[image]

As you can see the html attributes names are highlighted as the html tags (`each`, `onsubmit`). So I added a syntax to fix that (turn them to blue):

```
" #66d9ef
syn keyword tagFunction var this
syn match tagFunction "/\v\<\/?\w+\s+\w+\/?>" contained
hi def link tagFunction Define
```

But nothing happens, the color stay the same. I even used `contains` and `contained` so I'm not sure what's the problem. Is the `tagFunction` regex wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to match with the regex?

Comment: @JLILIAman the HTML attributes names in my example code `each`, `onsubmit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern starts with a `/` (and also escapes the second `/` as `\/`, which isn't necessary); you probably forgot to remove those when copying from the search history:

```
syn match tagFunction "\v\<\/?\w+\s+\w+/?>" contained
```

You can easily verifying your patterns by first yanking the pattern `yi"`, then assigning that to the search register `:let @/ = @@`. The `n` command will then jump to the next match and (with `:set hlsearch`) highlight all matches.

#### Further critique

Note that your `tagOperator` pattern is more general and includes (because of the `[^>]*` part) any `tagFunction` part. This ambiguity is dangerous, as now the correct matching depends on the ordering of the two `:syntax` commands. In this case, I think you can just make a `tagAttribute` contained in `tagOperator`, and define it roughly like this:

```
:syn match tagAttribute "\w\+={[^}]*}" contained
```

Comment: Thanks man. You've become my Vim hero. By the way I tried doing: `tagAttribute "\w\+\s\+"` to only highlight `each`, `onsubmit`. But the other words are also highlighted (e.g. `item`). I noticed you stopped using `zs` and `ze` after I included the `contains`. How can I do it to only highlight the attribute's names?

Comment: Can there be multiple attributes (`foo={bar} hi={ho}`)? Then, it's best to anchor the pattern to before the `=`: `tagAttribute "\w\+\ze="`. Your attempt will match (within `tagOperator`) _all_ words followed by whitespace.

Comment: ha, you're right. I wrote something similar. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, what a coincidence. It shows you're on the right way!

Comment: Yeah. Wow, I've learned a lot about regexs from you, more than in college. Thanks.